# anova_lm function for a single multiple linear regression model

Tags: multiple-regression, anova, linear-model

When using `anova_lm` from statsmodels with a single multiple linear regression model, how are statistics for each predictor calculated ?

E.g.

```
model = sm.formula.ols(mpg ~ cylinders + displacement + horsepower + weight + acceleration + year + origin, data = auto)

anova_lm(model)
```

[image]

How are `sum_sq`, `mean_sq` and `F` values calculated for each independent predictor (e.g.`horsepower`) ?